# How to convert a "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'" format in a dataframe to a datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, twitter, iso8601

How can I convert a "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'" format in a dataframe to a datetime format that I can further format to an index

`2021-01-02T05:22:58.000Z`  is one of the dates in the dataframe

i've tried this line of code:

```
df['created_at_tweet']= pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_tweet'], format=("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH :mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))
```

but i get the error

```
ValueError: time data '2021-01-02T01:43:32.000Z' does not match format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH :mm:ss.SSS'Z'' (match)
```

any ideas?

Comment: You've got a space after `HH` for no obvious reason in your format string. Just get rid of the space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: That's just not a valid parsing directive in Python. And basically, you can use pd.to_datetime *without* providing a `format` here.

Comment: I used pd.to_datetime and I don't get an error anymore. But the dates in the dataframe dont have a valid date format to create an index

All dates  in the created_at_tweet column are now:
<function to_datetime at 0x7fb6edb8a310>

Comment: Reload your data, then just `df['created_at_tweet']= pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_tweet'])`

Comment: `df['created_at_tweet']= pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_tweet'])` gives me the error `<class 'function'> is not convertible to datetime`

Comment: Sorry but I don't see much point in more guessing, can you please provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'created_at_tweet' : ['2021-01-02T01:43:32.000Z'], 'tweet' : ['Hello Twitter!']})

df['created_at_tweet']= pd.to_datetime(
  df['created_at_tweet'], 
  format=('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

yields

```
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you FObersteiner for your help
7shoe this solved the error

Comment: Great! Consider check-marking the answer to make it visible for people dealing with that problem in the future.